# Most efficient way to write spark streaming data into RDBMS

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a spark streaming job that consumes data from Kafka & writes to RDBMS. I am currently stuck because I do not know which would be the most efficient way to store this streaming data into RDBMS.

On searching, I found a few methods -

1. Using `DataFrame`
2. Using `JdbcRDD`
3. Creating connection & `PreparedStatement` inside `foreachPartition()` of rdd and using `PreparedStatement.insertBatch()`

I can not figure out which one would be the most efficient method of achieving my goal.

Same is the case with storing & retrieving data from HBase.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: have you tried any one of the above ? If not you can post..

Comment: I have used DataFrame to write to RDBMS. Not yet went to the part where I test the performance though.